# Isn't this a request for a "Poll" type answer?

Tags: discussion

Still trying to understand how things work...

Isn't this question asking for a "Poll"?

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18138/how-many-hours-do-you-expect-to-clock-in-a-40-hour-week

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Let's close this ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

I always tread lightly on migrated questions. Questions that get migrated here will be locked and unable to be edited if they are voted to close, and [I thought that post was sorely in need of an edit at the very least](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13223563#13223563):

> (it is in sore need of an edit at the very least, and will likely get closed and locked before it gets the edit it needs)

I was trying to manage the huge burden that was being caused by [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/what-is-a-friendly-way-to-let-managers-know-that-having-good-developers-is-a-p) (10k views in 24 hours!), and by the time I got around to thinking about an edit, it already had answers and had no close votes. So I passed on it.

I do think it was a poor question that should have been edited *prior* to migration, but that's a separate discussion entirely. As-is, I think it should be closed.

Comment: Okay, at this point, perhaps it isn't a bad idea to talk with the folks in Programmers chat about questions they intend to migrate this way. Whenever I migrate questions from one site to another, I generally edit it on the source site first before moving it over, since if it gets closed on the source site we can still easily reopen it. As an aside, I can try unlocking this one if you think it can be edited. Let me know.

Comment: @jmort, I suggest we find a developer to edit the question. I don't understand what agile is, and any edit I made would change it dramatically from 'how do I estimate sprints' to 'estimating 40 hours of work doesn't account for meetings or other things that come up, should I be taking that in to account in estimating the hours available, or increase the amount of time I think it will take to complete things based on meetings and the like?'

Comment: Just curious - why do 10k views cause a burden? What are you managing that is impacted by this kind of volume (which is large for Workplace but not for other Stackexchange sites)?

Comment: @joe, tons of traffic means voting, closing, and flagging. When I'm awake no one else is, so I am spending my time moderating rather than editing or answering which results in worse content.

Comment: @jmac - thanks. I thought the site was fairly automated. I didn't realize it depended on a lot of moderator action.

Comment: @jmac involving SE dev is not strictly necessary - you can draft the edited version right here, in this or in another, separate answer and ask moderators to unlock after edit is done. I did something like that at Prog meta once - drafted an answer, discussed question edit, then appealed to moderator to unlock and reopen - [worked like a charm](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3811/31260 "here"). No time pressure, no fear, solid back-up for moderator flag